# Continuous approximation of $L^p$ function.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am doing an exercise where we prove continuous $L^p$ functions are dense in $L^p(\mathbf{R})$ for finite $p\ge 1$. We define for $\epsilon >0$ $$
f_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_x^{x+\epsilon}f(t)\ dt.
$$I am asked to show $||f_\epsilon||_p<||f||_p$, that $f_\epsilon \to f$ in the $L^p$ norm as $\epsilon \to 0$ and finally that continuous functions are dense in $L^p$.

I have shown the first part, using Hölders one can show $|f_\epsilon(x)|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{\epsilon}}\left(\int_x^{x+\epsilon}|f(t)|^p\ dt\right)^\frac{1}{p}$. And then plugging this into $\int_\mathbf{R} |f_\epsilon(x)|^p\ dx$ simplifies nicely. Once we show $f_\epsilon \to f$, then I can see the last part, as each $f_\epsilon$ is defined as an indefinite integral, hence is absolutely continuous. However, I am stuck showing this second part. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $f_{\epsilon} \to f$ a.e. is Lebesgue'e Differentiation Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm Is the idea to use dominated convergence theorem then? If so, I'm not sure which $g$ would satisfy $|f_\epsilon(x)|<g(x)$.